# Relation between sides and angles.

Tags: geometry

Is this phrase safe to consider in general:

> > Equal sides of a polygon have corresponding equal angles

if not how would you refine or correct it

Example of a corresponding angle would be

[image]

Edited:
For example suppose you ignore the fact that the above triangle is an equilateral and treat it as a regular polygon.Then according to the above statement  Angle A and Angle B are both equal because Side A corresponds to angle A which is equal to SideB which corresponds to angle B

Comment: So does this mean that all the angles of a rhombus will be equal ?

Comment: how do you define a corresponding angle in a polygon?

Comment: Just clarified my question a bit more

Comment: how would you define corresponding angle for polygon of 4 or more sides??

Comment: @experimentX Nice question.. I guess then this statement only applies to triangles what do u think ?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construct a pentagon of all equal sides. Physically, out of pieces of straws or something. Note how you can bend it in any which way so that no angles are the same. So the question of "equal sides correspond to equal angles" is true for triangles, can *maybe* be rephrased in a way that's true for quadrilaterals (since there it forces two pairs of equal angles), but definitely fails to work in general.

A better statement to prove might be the reverse: Do equal angles of a polygon imply equal sides?

Comment: Yeah concluding it I believe this statement only holds for Triangles. I am also interested in the answer to Do equal angles of a polygon imply equal sides? but then experimentX asked a very good question which angles represent which side ?

Comment: @Rajeshwar: if you become interested in a different question from your original question, feel free to ask a new one; if you change this one then the answers will look wrong

Comment: benmachine Ill ask a new one then.. thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

There is a statement about *equal* triangles that says: in equal triangles the angles opposite to equal sides are equal, i.e. is $\Delta ABC$ = $\Delta A_1B_1C_1$, then $AB=A_1B_1\implies \angle C =\angle C_1$. If you want to generalise this in any direction, you must say something about the polygons in question and the way how angles "correspond" to sides, otherwise the picture is too loose to make a definite statement

Comment: Is this statement only limited to equilateral triangles or could it be applied to other types of triangles as well ?

Comment: it applies to any two or more equal triangles

Comment: you mean any kind of a triangle

Comment: yes, to any kind